# KendoGrid getting row hierarchy cell rows

Tags: kendo-grid

Does anyone here have an idea on what's going on with my code? What am I doing wrong? I couldn't make hierarchical details to show up.

Here is my code:

```
detailExpand: function (e) {
                    var expandedRowId = e.masterRow.data('uid');

                    var currentRow = $('tr[data-uid=' + expandedRowId + ']');

                    var rowDetails = currentRow.find('.k-detail-row');
                }
```

Hope someone could help. Thanks.

Comment: can you create jsfiddle with sample code,that helps to identify the issue.

Comment: Please edit and clarify what problem/error you received. Are you unable to get value in expandedRowId? then try `var masterDataItem = masterGrid.dataItem(e.masterRow); masterDataItem.uid`